# Quartz Get trigger description

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Is there a function in the API that returns language description of a trigger? For example,
cron trigger expression="0 0 0 L * ?"
Language I'm looking for is "Fires at 0:00:00 every last day of the month" (Or something like that)

I want to use this to give feed back to user of what schedules are created. I'm hoping I don't have to parse the expression myself. I search Google but have came empty, maybe I'm not using the right words to search for.

I'm using the .NET version. But if there is a java function out there I could probably figure out how to port it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a question similiar to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469276/convert-cron-expression-into-nice-description-strings-is-there-a-library-for-ja)

I think your going to have to write something yourself for this

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Don't know how my searches did not pull that question up. It's exactly what I asked.

Comment: @JavaGeek I guess you should post your answer so that Rick can accept it. I don't think it's an exact duplicate of the question you linked, as this one is really related to Quartz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a question similiar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469276/convert-cron-expression-into-nice-description-strings-is-there-a-library-for-ja) I think your going to have to write something yourself for this.

Comment: Yes I had to write something myself.