# Spring cron expression for 3 AM

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am using Java - Spring - Quartz Scheduler. I want to run job by 3 AM in the morning and following is my cron expression.

```
0 0 3 * * ?
```

Can somebody tell me is it the correct one? Will it execute twice in 24 hour 3 PM and 3 AM?

Comment: Yes this is correct, you can verify it by [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469276/convert-cron-expression-into-nice-description-strings-is-there-a-library-for-ja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is correct, you can verify it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469276/convert-cron-expression-into-nice-description-strings-is-there-a-library-for-ja), and it takes 0-23 for Hhour field so it  will invoke at 3 am

Answer (score 4):

I have checked your expression in the [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

This only works for 3:00 AM every day. If you need for 3 AM and 3 PM, use this:

```
0 0 3/12 1/1 * ? *
```